# Matplotlib create surface plot (x,y,z,color) given csv data - getting wrong colors

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, visualization

How can I read in four columns of data to create a surface plot which is colored by the fourth variable? In my case, the data was generated using four nested for loops, so the rightmost columns change most frequently while the leftmost columns change least frequently.

Here is what I've tried so far. It is creating a solid colored graph but the coloring is wrong.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import pylab
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dat = open('ex.csv', 'w')
dat.write('x,y,z,c\n')
for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
             dat.write(','.join([str(s) for s in [x,y,x+y,x+y,'\n']]))
dat.close()

fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf()
subdat = np.genfromtxt('ex.csv', delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
X = subdat[:,0]
Y = subdat[:,1]
Z = subdat[:,2]
C = subdat[:,3]

xi = np.linspace(X.min(),X.max(),100)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(),Y.max(),100)

zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
ci = griddata((X, Y), C, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xig, yig = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
surf = ax1.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi,facecolors=cm.rainbow(ci))

m = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.rainbow)
m.set_array(ci)
col = plt.colorbar(m)
plt.show()
```

[image]
(coloring is wrong, should be the same as elevation value with continuous gradient)

Comment: Are you sure that the x,y,z point form a single surface?  And you say, "unstructured data", but that data looks highly structured.  What are you referring to?

Comment: What I meant is that it's not arranged in a grid. I'll take that out I see that it's confusing.

Comment: Make sure the new size after reshape is compatible with the old data. In this case the size of your `dat['var1']` is 11 and you are trying to reshape it into 3X5. May be you need to fill in missing values for some combination of 'var1' and 'var2'.

Comment: @hashmuke sorry I edited my question so heavily your comment no longer appears relevant. Thank you for this comment it helped me develop my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the `facecolors` aren't normalizing as might be expected.  Try this, which does the normalizing explicitely:

```
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize()
surf = ax1.plot_surface(xig, yig, zi, facecolors=cm.rainbow(norm(ci)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Why are the j's here: `grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:100j]`? Is there a way this can be done for any X,Y data? It looks like your solution is limited to the bounds of my example.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I am leaving it un-checked, as I am looking for a solution to the general problem.

Comment: Also your color bar is off by a factor of 20 for some reason

Comment: @kilojoules: I've updated my answer.  In my update, everything in the code is as is in your code except for the displayed lines. (In particular, your term `(xi[None,:], yi[:,None])`, which I first thought was the problem, seems to be fine.)